# Webdriver : how to set IE in virtual environment?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am setting up the Virtual Environment for my grid-based Webdriver tests. And sure enough, there are problems with IE driver.

First of all, Internet Options → Security should have the same Protected Mode setting. It's an easy fix if you have an access to the browser, but in my case, I won't have physical access to the browser.
In Webdriver's FAQ it says you can do the following:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();    
capabilities.set(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Ruby bindings have no reference to setting up this capability in IE. It there a way to code it out in Ruby?

The other thing is what can be done against "unsecure connection" pop-ups? Again, they are easy to deal with manually after the first run, but what about running "clean" IE instance each time?

There are probably more concerns,
I'd like to hear your opinion.

Thank you!